# How to add a getter from one object to another

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I made a similar question not too long ago, but I have another twist to it. Suppose I have this:

```
  var config = {
    a: {
        value: '',
        get getValue(): {
            return this.valueType
        }
    },
    b: {
        value: '',
        get getValue(): {
            return this.value
        }
    },
    c: {
        value: {
          d: '',
          e: '',
          f: ''
        },
        get getValue(): {
            return this.d + " " + this.e + " " + this.f
        }
    }
  }
```

Then, I am doing this:

```
  assignConfig(conf) {
    array.push({
      value: { ...config[conf] } //conf Could be a, b, c
    }
  }
```

The idea is that I can call getValue and get the data in that format, but I will be calling it from the array where I'm pushing the config. The values inside valueType will be changing, since they are being used in an ngModel. When I try this, getValue is always empty. Is this possible to do? Maybe there's another way to approach this.

Comment: Looks like you want [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#copying_accessors); copying accessors requires grabbing property descriptors because otherwise you're just *using* the accessor.

Comment: I made a mistake in my example, I've modified how I'm adding the config.

Comment: Why do you want to do `{value: { ...config[conf] }}` instead of just `{value: config[conf] }`?

Comment: Because there might be multiple instances of `config[conf]` in the array, and if I do it like you mentioned, the values will repeat everywhere instead of being new values.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could drop the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/w6BdYw) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared/unimported types or values.